# How to count total number of people who sent message to my Facebook Business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are many people more than 3k sent message to my Facebook Business page at different times. For my business planing I have to know exactly how many people sent message.

I saw [messenger-counter](https://pypi.org/project/messenger-counter/).

> Note: To use this software you need to download your data directly from Facebook (in JSON format).

```
pip install messenger-counter
python -m mc count "facebook-YourName.zip"
```

For downloadig facebook page data I want to follow [How do I export my Facebook Page's insights data?](https://www.facebook.com/help/972879969525875)
. But I don't find the **Export Data** option in new facebook version I use.

> From your News Feed, click **Pages** in the left menu.

> Go to your Page.

> Click **Insights** in the left menu.

> Click **Export Data** in the top right.

> Select a data type, file format and date range. You may also need to choose a layout.

> Click **Export Data** again.

I can access my page using access token found in graph API exploler.

```
import facebook

at = "page access token"
# pid = <my page id>
api = facebook.GraphAPI( at )
args = {'fields' : 'message'}  #requested fields
conv = api.get_object( 'me/conversations', **args)
print(len(conv['data']))
msg = api.get_object( conv['data'][24]['id']+'/messages')
for el in msg['data']:
    content = api.get_object( el['id'], **args)   #adding the field request
    print(content)
```

Is it possible using graph API, Facebook developer, python or using any language?

**UPDATED**

```
import facebook

at = "Page access token"
api = facebook.GraphAPI( at )
conv = api.get_object( 'me/conversations', fields='senders', limit=5000)
print(len(conv['data']))
```

Results `499` at most. But actually my page has more than `3600` conversations/senders.